# Global multidimensional array of a struct in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to build a simple tournament in c, but I'm struggling to use a multidimensional array of struct round.

```
typedef struct round{
   enum role  myrole;
   int *opponent;
   int flag;
} *round_t;

static round_t** rounds;

void buildTournament(int players){
   int roundCount = ceil_log2(players);

   rounds = malloc( players * sizeof *rounds );

   size_t row;
   for (row = 0; row < roundCount; ++row)
       rounds[row] = malloc( roundCount * sizeof **rounds );

   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < players; i++)
   {
        for (k = 0; k <= roundCount; k++)
        {
            round_t round = malloc(sizeof(round_t));
            if(i % 2 == 0)
            {
                round->myrole = WINNER;
            }
            else
            {
                round ->myrole = LOSER;
            }
            rounds[i][k] = round;
        }
   }

}
```

With 8 players, it throws a seg fault writing to rounds[3][0], which is the 10th memory location.  This makes me think I'm only allocating 9 memory locations to the array.  Obviously, I'm new to C, so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: `for (k = 0; k <= roundCount; k++)` should be `k < roundCount` otherwise you index out of bounds for `rounds[i][k]`

Comment: Thanks, I changed my original implementation which started k at 1 and used rounds[i][k-1] for a simpler explanation for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allocating enough space here

```
round_t round = malloc(sizeof(round_t));
```

your fault is that you declared `round_t` as a pointer to a `struct round` which hides the fact that `round_t` is `struct round *` from you, hence `sizeof(round_t)` seemed natural but it's wrong because it's allocating space for a pointer, and not for a strcut, change it like this

```
round_t round = malloc(sizeof(*round));
```

or

```
round_t round = malloc(sizeof(struct round));
```

Don't `typedef` pointers it makes your code very confusing, and if you must `typedef` a pointer, try to imply that it is a pointer in it's name, something like

```
typedef struct round{
    enum role  myrole;
    int *opponent;
    int flag;
} round_t;
typedef round_t *round_p;
```

and also, as @[rpattiso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2726734/rpattiso) commented, you should fix the `for` loop condition.